# change svg size according to media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

```
<svg width='1175' height='400'>
```

How do I change width and height of the `svg img` with media queries?

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1680px) {
   svg{
      width:1720;
      height:400;
      }
}
```

This does not work.

Comment: Why are you not using `px` or no `%`.?, it's always ideal to wrap the `SVG` to a div and make it `responsive` according to your page.!

Answer (score 2):

you can change width and height with media queries like the following but it's always ideal to wrap the SVG to a `div or viewbox` and make it responsive according to your page.!

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1680px) {
 svg{
   width:1720px; //or any css units
   height:400px; //or any css units
 }
}
```

Comment: That worked for me, I also did use % rather px when defining width and height

Answer (score 1):

Prefer the [`viewbox` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) on your svg, rather than the `width` and `height`. This way you can easily adapt the size of your svg, keeping the right ratio.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typo: missing closing "}".
Also you should always declare px if you want to use them. Good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the SVG size is relatively an easier task. Refer below:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1680px) {
  svg {
    width:1720px; //as a rule of thumb, always give px,%,vw units etc.
    height:400px;
   }
}
```

Alternatively, We can use the SVG viewBox, which is quite different from viewport(your browser window). You can define the position and the dimension of an SVG viewport using

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 250 250"></svg>
```

You might be looking for CSS property which is proposed in SVG2.
The proposal is in this PR : 
[Proposal: Promote SVG Viewbox to a CSS property, extend to all transformable elements
#7](https://github.com/w3c/fxtf-drafts/issues/7). Happy Coding!